# Why $\lim_{n\to \infty} ({3^n+2^n\over 3^n-2^ni^n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} ({3^n+2^n\over 3^n-2^n}) \ $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

This week I was introduced to the limits of complex sequences. It is actually pretty simple because it's mostly the same compared to real sequences. However, there is one thing - Why is:

> $\lim_{n\to \infty} ({3^n+2^n\over 3^n-2^ni^n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} ({3^n+2^n\over 3^n-2^n}) \ $

Where does the $i^n$ go? We have not discussed the limit of $i^n$ so far, but I should be able to explain this.

Comment: In the first expression, divide top and bottom by $3^n$. At the bottom, we get $1-i^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$. As $n\to\infty$, the $i^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ part dies. If you do something similar in the second expression, the $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ part dies.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : Your comment is the answer. Post it so! :)

Comment: It probably is. I actually simplified the expression the same way but was really unsure (for whatever reason) about the "$i^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ dies" - part as n goes to infinity.

Comment: I think that the answer by Calvin Lin is very satisfactory. The comment just adds a little detail.

Comment: @kitkat4.4: The norm of $i^n \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ is $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$, and approaches $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It didn't magically disappear. You should show that the limit of both values is 1.

---

A similar question would be to ask: Why is $\cos 0 = \tan \frac{\pi}{4}$?

There isn't any special relationship, just that both sides happen to be equal to 1.

Comment: But isn't $\cos 0 = e^{i 2 \pi}$?